# Is DD4T GetPage case sensitive in Tridion9.5?

Tags: dd4t, sites-9.5

For retrieval of pages from the broker DB, we are using DD4Tcontroller GetPage and passing the URL from the browser address bar.

In our old installation (2013sp1) this was case insensitive so if you pass "/test/TEST/index.aspx" or "/test/test/index.aspx" both would return the same result.

In the new version, we notice that it only returns a result when the passed URL matches the value in the DB exactly. So in the DB if the URL is "/test/TEST/index.aspx" it won't work for other cases.

Is there some configuration we are missing or something we are overlooking on how to ignore the case?

We are using DD4T latest version (2.5) with Tridion 9.5

Comment: Is you new installation on the same database? There could be settings with SQL/other that impact queries.

Comment: It's on a new database. In the meantime I've tried to retrieve the page through the public API and graphQL. That works and ignores case. I'll update the post if we manage to get it fully working.

Answer (score 1):

DD4T relies on the content service (or the broker if you still run with an 'on-prem' CD stack) to retrieve pages. The pages are retrieved from the database. Whether the URL is case sensitive or not, depends on the settings of your database. If you use SQL Server, the **Collation** determines this. For Oracle I'm not sure, but it is probably a setting there as well.